# Does geth or parity in development chain mode support methods like hardhat_setSorageAt or is there a way to manipulate EOA?

Tags: go-ethereum, hardhat, openethereum

I wan’t to create more sustainable test network for my develop project. Hardhat node gets slowed down with the time and even crashes.

I am wondering is there a modified geth rpc client supporting some of the hardhat’s cheat codes?

Answer (score 0):

Neither Geth nor Parity (Parity's actually been deprecated for quite some time) provide the "cheat code" ability since their goal being node clients following the Ethereum spec.

If you are not satisfied with Hardhat, though, have a look at Foundry's [Anvil](https://book.getfoundry.sh/anvil/). Anvil has `anvil_setStorageAt`. Check [the reference](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/anvil/) too.